# how to set a progress bar any website process in Windows form applcation

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am not familiar with programming concept.   i am make on the INTERNET explorer like that firefox. I want to set a progress bar as work on any website download (process). if our site is done then progress bar a complete.  I have no idea solve this problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? It is not clear what you want to do or what your problem is.

Comment: sir g i making  a explorer. i want to add a progress bar tell me site of progress.

Comment: Are you creating your own C# Winforms "Browser", like a 'BangerChrome' Browser? One topic is "how to use WinForm progressbars" and another is "how to create a browser" (way more complex).

Comment: sir g i know used the progress bar and i have done some parts of the browser.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly then I think you want a progress bar to show how much of a website is loaded, or a program downloaded. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the WinForm WebBrowser control, make sure its ProgressChanged event is set and have it update the progressBar something like this:

```
private void webBrowser1_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("e.MaximumProgress " + e.MaximumProgress);
    progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.MaximumProgress;

    Debug.WriteLine("e.CurrentProgress " + e.CurrentProgress);
    progressBar1.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
}
```

You'll have to experiment with it to see what it’s doing… also, if your internet is fast, your barely going to see any progress movement at all on the bar.

Otherwise, you would have to re-create the “plumbing” code yourself to fetch the page and become intimately familiar w/ the low leve protocols  in able to measure download progress like that.